# Powershell script to set/update existing managed properties in sharepoint (Not create them or get them)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

`$newmp =Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity`

has anyone used this method, i have been trying to work with it, i have been successful in setting description and retrievable, the rest of the properties such as searchable,sortable have boolean values but i cant set any of them does any one have the correct code to using it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spenterprisesearchmetadatamanagedproperty?view=sharepoint-ps), `Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty` doesn't allow you to update these properties through this particular commandlet.  What I've used in the past is something like the following:

```
Function Update-ManagedProperty([string]$name) 
{
    $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication;
    $mp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity $name;

    $mp.Searchable = $true;
    $mp.Queryable = $true;
    $mp.Sortable = $true;
    $mp.Retrievable = $true;
    $mp.Refinable = $true;
    $mp.Update();

    $mp | Write-Output;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that did it.  any idea how to update mapping as that function does not support updating mappings please and thank you.

Comment: Do you know how I could do the same action but on sharepoint online ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to update the managed property:

```
 $LogTime = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm
 $LogFile = ".\UpdateManagedPropertyPatch-$LogTime.rtf"

 #start-transcript $logfile

 # Add SharePoint PowerShell Snapin


 if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null ) {
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
 }

 $scriptBase = split-path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent
 Set-Location $scriptBase

 $OutputPath = $scriptBase + "\" + "ManagedPropErrors.txt"


 if (test-path $OutputPath)
 {
     remove-item $OutputPath
 }


 $csvfile = $scriptBase + "\" + "EditManagedProp.csv"
 Import-csv $csvfile | where {

 $searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

 $ManagedProperty = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Identity $_.ManagedPropertyName -ea silentlycontinue

 if($ManagedProperty)
 {
     $ManagedProperty.Searchable = $true
     $ManagedProperty.Queryable = $true
     $ManagedProperty.Sortable = $true
     $ManagedProperty.Retrievable = $true
     $ManagedProperty.Refinable = $true
     $ManagedProperty.SafeForAnonymous = $true
     $ManagedProperty.update()
     write-host "The searchable, queryable, Sortable, Retrievable and Refinable for the managed property" $_.ManagedPropertyName "has been enabled successfully ...... Done !" -fore green
 }
 else
 {
     Write-Host -f Yellow "The specified managed property " $_.ManagedPropertyName " does not exists... Please check whether you have given valid managed property name"
     $a = "The specified managed property " + $_.ManagedPropertyName + " does not exists... Please check whether you have given valid crawled property name"| out-file $OutputPath -append
 }


 }
 #stop-transcript
```

Reference:

[How To Update Managed Property As Searchable, Queryable, Sortable, Refinable, Retrievable In SharePoint 2013 Using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Update-Managed-Property-as-Searchable-Queryable-Sortable-Refinable-Retrievable-in-SharePoint-2013-using-PowerShell)